# How can I run my gif only once using FLAnimatedImage?

Tags: ios, swift, gif

I'm using xcode 10.1 and swift 4.2, I have a gif which I made with Photoshop and it plays one time in browser and in android studio. 
But when I import it in xcode and click on it in storyboard, it plays for ever. It also plays several time in my virtual simulator.

I'm creating an IOS webview app and I want to play this gif once in my splash screen and stop it at the last frame, until my webview loads.

I'm using FLAnimatedImage, I found a similar question to mine, but I couldn't find my solution. That's why I'm asking again.

I do not want to change the main library files, since I have another gif which I want to play it forever. So I just need to stop the first gif in the last frame.

You can see a small part of my code:

```
@IBOutlet var LogoView: FLAnimatedImageView!

LogoView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
LogoView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
LogoView!.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "logo_gif", withExtension: "gif")!)
            LogoView.animatedImage = FLAnimatedImage(animatedGIFData: imageData)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you can play with properties: `loopLeft` and `loopCountdown`: http://www.dndgit.com/marek/FLAnimatedImage/commit/b5a09bf2b1b551e6952636d6c52d848135d0c274?view=parallel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a loopCompletionBlock to your imageView

```
self.imageView.loopCompletionBlock = {_ in
    self.imageView.stopAnimating()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for your response. Should I write it in my ViewController.swift file?

Comment: Yes, where you configure the imageView, typically in the ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You may use following library.

https://github.com/wangjwchn/AImage

```
   let image = AImage(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "gif")!)

/* Create AImageView */
let imageview = AImageView(frame:CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 50.0, width: 380.0, height: 212.0))

/* Add AImage to AImageView */
imageview.add(image: image!)

/* Start displaying animated image */
imageview.play = true

...
...

/* Stop displaying animated image */
imageview.play = false
```

pass true to play property when you want it to start and and pass false when you want to stop.

You can also use this AImageView class  from storyboard too, change UIImageView to AImageView from class inspector.